# How to rotate FBX files in 90 degree while running on a path in iTween in unity 3d

Tags: path, unity-game-engine

I am doing one racing game,in which I used iTween path systems to smooth camera turning in turns,iTween path systems works fine(special thanks to Bob Berkebile) Here first I used one cube to follow path and it works fine in turning But my problem is instead of using cube I used FBX(character) to follow path here when turn comes character will not move This is my problem Image:
[image]

I want this type:

[image]

How to Slove this problem?

Comment: try to setup rotation in fbx file by your 3d app